# Issue with the $mdDialog.show(confirm), not able to execute the code below this dialog directives in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angular-material, angularjs-directive, mddialog

I'm finding this issue with `$mdDialog.show(confirm)`, the code below the dialog function executes even before the popup arise.

I can handle by setting a flag to restrict the execution of below code. but after the completion of the dialog activity it goes to `Error(ie, resolvePromise())` without executing the below code:

```
//This is the code I have used.

var confirm = $mdDialog.confirm()
             .title('Early Dispatch Date Available.')
             .textContent('Do you want to reschedule and Change Quantity.')
              .ariaLabel('day')
             .ok('Yes')
             .cancel('Plan on Date');

$mdDialog.show(confirm).then(function (obj)
{
    $scope.targetDates[lastItem].Qty = 0;
    return;
}, function () {                
    condition = 'QtyLessThanCap';
});

//for example,this is the code which gets executed even before the comfirmation dialog pops up..

angular.forEach($scope.targetDates, function (Datess) 
{
      totalCalQty = totalCalQty + parseInt(Datess['Qty']);                   
});
```

I want the codes to be executed in the order I have coded them,I mean the below code need to be executed only after the confirmation dialog activity.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can't you just move your `angular.forEach` processing into the "`.then()`" function?

Comment: @BrendanGreen, No i have different scenarios, that dialog box is used only at certain cases but the below codes needs to `angular.forEach` executes all the time. and also i may need to use another `mdDialog` inside this `mdDialog` function, its complicate to use same code inside `.then()`.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I've been able to deal with the same type of functionality is by splitting the function, so for example you have an action function that determines whether you need a modal or can just calculate the total:

```
function something() { // if modal show modal.then(doSomething) }
```

then the actual calculation function which can be called directly, or from any level of mdModal.then():

```
function doSomething() { // calculate total }
```

It's probably not as pretty as you're looking for but it works.